# How to attach to a running shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, debugging, gdb

Is it possible, i.e. using gdb?
What's needed?

```
12606 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/bash -c /xxx/bin/dispatch.start
12626 ?        S      0:00  \_ /bin/bash /xxx/bin/waitpower.sh
13831 ?        S      0:00      \_ /bin/sh ./wn-mps1086-generex start
```

I want to attach to waitpower.sh and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
retty 12626
```

http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/ "retty is a tiny tool that lets you attach processes running on other terminals."

Comment: can i use it to attach at the begining, like, before the proccess is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach gdb using process id of your shell script :

```
sudo gdb -p pid
```

Comment: but i'm afraid I can't debug a shell script with gdb.

Comment: I checked and you are right, supported languages for gdb are C/C++, Go. See the whole list here [Supported-Languages](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Supported-Languages.html#Supported-Languages)